# Decryption of XML file is working just on single machine

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, encryption

I writing application which need to download from the internet encrypted XML file, decrypt it and take from it some info.

For testing purpose, I put my XML file in public link and when I`m running the application I'm getting inconsistent behavior.

This is my code which takes the encrypted file and decrypt it using my decryption method:

```
                const string settingsFileUrl = @"sharedlink.com...";
                XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                myXmlDocument.Load(settingsFileUrl);

                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = @"gf154de4-12f1-430a-8210-63fde92fbb17";
                //This private key is here just for testing purpose
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
                Utilities.Decryptor.Decrypt(myXmlDocument, rsaKey, "rsaKey");
```

this is my decryption code:

```
 internal class Decryptor
    {
        public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
        {
            // Check the arguments.   
            if (Doc == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
            if (Alg == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
            if (KeyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");

            // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
            EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(Doc);

            // Add a key-name mapping. 
            // This method can only decrypt documents 
            // that present the specified key name.
            exml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, Alg);

            // Decrypt the element.
            exml.DecryptDocument();

        }
    }
```

When I debuging this code at my primary machine everything works like a charm.
When I'm debuging it at my secondary machine I'm getting the error "bad data" from the line `Utilities.Decryptor.Decrypt(myXmlDocument, rsaKey, "rsaKey");`

I double checked and my secondary machine has access to the xml file.
I don`t have any clue what can be the problem.
help please :-(

---

update:
this is my encryption code:

```
  public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementToEncrypt, string EncryptionElementID, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
       {
           // Check the arguments. 
           if (Doc == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
           if (ElementToEncrypt == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("ElementToEncrypt");
           if (EncryptionElementID == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("EncryptionElementID");
           if (Alg == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
           if (KeyName == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");

           //////////////////////////////////////////////// 
           // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument 
           // object and create a new XmlElemnt object. 
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////
           XmlElement elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementToEncrypt)[0] as XmlElement;

           // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found. 
           if (elementToEncrypt == null)
           {
               throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");

           }
           RijndaelManaged sessionKey = null;

           try
           {
               ////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
               // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class 
               // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the 
               // a new random symmetric key. 
               ////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

               // Create a 256 bit Rijndael key.
               sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
               sessionKey.KeySize = 256;

               EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

               byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);
               //////////////////////////////////////////////// 
               // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate 
               // it with the desired encryption information. 
               ////////////////////////////////////////////////

               EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
               edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
               edElement.Id = EncryptionElementID;
               // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the 
               // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption.

               edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);
               // Encrypt the session key and add it to an EncryptedKey element.
               EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();

               byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, Alg, false);

               ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);

               ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

               // Create a new DataReference element 
               // for the KeyInfo element.  This optional 
               // element specifies which EncryptedData 
               // uses this key.  An XML document can have 
               // multiple EncryptedData elements that use 
               // different keys.
               DataReference dRef = new DataReference();

               // Specify the EncryptedData URI.
               dRef.Uri = "#" + EncryptionElementID;

               // Add the DataReference to the EncryptedKey.
               ek.AddReference(dRef);
               // Add the encrypted key to the 
               // EncryptedData object.

               edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));
               // Set the KeyInfo element to specify the 
               // name of the RSA key. 


               // Create a new KeyInfoName element.
               KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();

               // Specify a name for the key.
               kin.Value = KeyName;

               // Add the KeyInfoName element to the 
               // EncryptedKey object.
               ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
               // Add the encrypted element data to the 
               // EncryptedData object.
               edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
               //////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
               // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument 
               // object with the EncryptedData element. 
               ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               // re-throw the exception. 
               throw e;
           }
           finally
           {
               if (sessionKey != null)
               {
                   sessionKey.Clear();
               }

           }

       }
```

Maybe it will help

---

Update 2:

I found at ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) user comment about the encryption method.
He wrote the next comment:
The posted sample isn't working because they aren't using the same keys. Not only on different machines: running the program on the same machine twice should not work either (didn't work for me), because they use different random keys every time.
try adding this code after creating your key:

```
key = new RijndaelManaged();

byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Password1234"); //password here
byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Salt"); // salt here (another string)
PasswordDeriveBytes p = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes);
// sizes are devided by 8 because [ 1 byte = 8 bits ]
key.IV = p.GetBytes(key.BlockSize / 8);
key.Key = p.GetBytes(key.KeySize / 8);
```

Now the program is using the same key and initial vector, and Encrypt and Decrypt should work on all machines.
Also, consider renaming key to algorithm, otherwise this is very misleading. I'd say it's a bad, not-working-well example from MSDN.

I tried use it but I'm not sure where and which key do I need to provide at the decryption method.
Maybe you will understand it better than me.
Thx

Answer (score 3):

`"gf154de4-12f1-430a-8210-63fde92fbb17"` is not a RSA private key - it's way too short.  You're assigning it to a field called `KeyContainerName`, so I would guess that it's just a name for a private key that's stored somewhere on your PC by the Windows encryption APIs.  Since the other PC doesn't have that key installed, it doesn't work.

I'm not a Windows encryption expert, so I don't know how to fix it, but I hope this helps you find out!

Comment: Your explanation sound reasonable. How can I provide this private key to other machines?